# User filters in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a dashboard in Tableau and I am giving right access by filters.

If I wanna give access to roberto to the cs team I add the following:

```
IIF([language] = 'cs' , "roberto", ",") +...
```

How would it be if I wanna spcficially want to restrict to roberto to the CS team? Opossite as above...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to fully understand the question. Taking a stab perhaps a calculated field as follows would work?

```
[language]='cs' AND USERNAME() = 'roberto'
```

Put it on the filter shelf and set to True. If the language = cs and the user is roberto it will return data.